# Does Jmeter run everything in its own JVM, or create a JVM for each thread group?

Tags: java, jvm, jmeter

It seems to me like Jmeter might be running all thread group within its own JVM. Is this true or does Jmeter create new JVM's for different thread groups and/or samplers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All in one JVM. You can run more than one instance of JMeter though :)